# Unobtrusive validation attributes rendered for nullable DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this setup:

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Start)
}
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Start must be a date." id="Start" name="Start" type="datetime" value="" />
```

This HTML includes the unobtrusive validation attributes. Why is that? I was under the impression that there would be no validation if the ViewModel property is a nullable DateTime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem had to do with Globalization. Since I'm supporting multiple cultures, I'm including the jquery-globalize scripts and added the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return Globalize.parseDate(value);
    }
});
```

Globalize.parseDate failed on an empty value. This only becomes obvious on nullable date fields, where an empty value should be considered valid. If I replace it with

```
return value == '' ? null : Globalize.parseDate(value);
```

everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Because MVC is smart enough to figure out that since the type of your property is DateTime then whatever is placed in there must at the minimum be a valid date. In other words the validation restrictions placed are due to the fact that your property is of type DateTime. The validation will only be enforced is something is entered into the field.

Comment: The problem is that while ModelState.IsValid = true in the controller, the client-side unobtrusive validation picks up the attributes and displays a client-side error if the field is left blank.

Comment: That is highly unlikely. I have the same scenario in many of my projects and I use nullable DateTime fields all the time. I never experience this sort of an issue. Are you perhaps using some sort of custom model binder in your project? Is your property decorated with Required attribute?

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time setting up a test project to demo the issue led me to the root problem... You are of course correct, see my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old post, it appears near the top of the Google search results when the search term "MVC Date Validation for nullable field" is entered.

HTML5 has an excellent solution:
use `@type = "date"`, and `@min` and `@max` attributes for the field like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.YourPropertyHere, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { id = "YourPropertyID", @class = "form-rounded", @type = "date", @min = "2019-01-01", @max = "2099-01-01" })
```

and also the validation message:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YourPropertyHere, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The `@class` attribute references Bootstrap's css.